# ImportError: No module named jupyter_core.command, path added with no issue persists

Tags: module, jupyter-notebook

This has been discussed before but today I am seeing it again in my new company and it is a bit different this time:

I am doing a jupyter installation, first thing is I need to run the command to generate config file:

```
$ jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

I got error saying

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/jupyter", line 4, in 
>       import jupyter_core.command ImportError: No module named jupyter_core.command

I found a similar discussion [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/jupyter-core-command/td-p/41800), following it solved same issue in my previous company (both Anaconda 2/3 installed) but not this new company(Anaconda 4).

I suspect this relates to the needed library is missing, so I found the library's location and added it to $PATH

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/pkgs/jupyter_core-4.2.0-py27_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

I ran the command again and the error persists.

What am I missing here? should I run any magic Linux command after the export?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I faced the same problem too, and I solve it by change ~/.local/ group and owner from root to my account.I think it's a kind of permission issue, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I change my owner from root to my account, then something wrong I met, my current account can't create related dirs, so, I changed my owner to root to create neccessary dir, meanwhile, chmod 777 to that dir. finally, my problem solved